# elasticsearch not working if I change elasticsearch.yml?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm very new to `elasticsearch`. I'm trying to change `elasticsearch.yml` like `node.name` or `node.cluster` after this my `localhost:9200` does't loads 
any idea

Comment: can you provide more information? What is the error? posting your edited elasticsearch.yml can help too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you omit space after `:` in settings.

Wrong settings:

```
node.name:node1
cluster.name:cluster1
```

Correct Settings:

```
node.name: node1
cluster.name: cluster1
```

Obviously elastic settings is in **yml** format, and in yml you must watch out spaces and tabs!